# Set R library directory during configure when building from source on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r

Building R with these commands on Ubuntu 16.04

```
wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf R-3.4.1.tar.gz
cd R-3.4.1; ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-R-shlib; make; make install
```

leads to the R library being set to /usr/local/lib/R/library

Whereas installing R using "apt-get install r-base" installs packages to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library

Is there a configuration option for building from source that will create /usr/local/lib/R/site-library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may confuse a *compile-time option* for the *top-level directory* with a run-time option / configuration time option.

At *compile-time* you can only set the top-level via `--prefix` as you have done.

At *run-time* (ie startup or during a session) you can set the `.libPath()` for `library()`.  For Debian / Ubuntu we do that in `/etc/R/Renviron` with this:

```
# edd Apr 2003  Allow local install in /usr/local, also add a directory for
#               Debian packaged CRAN packages, and finally the default dir
# edd Jul 2007  Now use R_LIBS_SITE, not R_LIBS
R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library'}
```

You can customize this to your heart's content. See `help(Startup)`.